# How do I parse an integer, using the rule that +5 is not valid but 5 is?

Tags: c#, integer, error-checking

My program asks the user to input a number from 1 - 10 in a text box in. When I the user inputs the number I have it converted into an `int`, by using this:

```
if (!int.TryParse(inputBox.Text, out input))
```

I used the `!` because if the number cannot be `TryParse`'d into a int it throws an error to the user.

This works, until I enter a number that begins with a `+`, for example `+5`, or `+1`. It isn't catching the fact that there is a `+` in front of the `int`. If I enter more than one `+` it throws an error like it should.

How would someone make an error proofing line(s) of code that checks for this type of input?

Comment: So you're saying that the string "+5" successfully parses to an int, right?

Comment: Yes, but it takes off the **+**, and I need something that catches it before and throws an error to the user

Comment: TryParse() != CheckFormat(). TryParse attempts to get an integer value from a string. It may be really smart and really good at doing so, including (and definitely not limited)  to realizing that +5 = 5.

Comment: That's because the string "+5" successfully parses to an integer value of 5. What is your question?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I need it to throw an error to the user.

Comment: Why? +5 successfully parses.

Comment: Yes, but that is not within the parameters that I want the user to input. It works perfectly fine that way, but in this case I don't want it to work like that. I want it to throw an error.

Comment: FYI, `TryParse` outputs a bool, so you can easily set it up as a basic `if/else` statement: `if (!int.TryParse(inputBox.Text, out input)) { //do something } else { //do something else }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to allow 1-10 without the positive sign (+).

```
int number;
var input = numberTextBox.Text;
if (!input.StartsWith("+") && int.TryParse(input, out number))
{
    //valid input, check if it's between 1-10
}
```

But I think the requirement is really strange. "+10" is considered the same as "10", it is a valid input.

Comment: I like this more then anything I've seen. I know it's bazaar, I'm trying to make it so that there is no hiccups in the code. Yeah it's still a valid input, but since it is not within the parameters of want I want, I need it to throw an user end error. Thank you!

Comment: @BryanOlesky A bazaar is an enclosed marketplace. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar

Comment: @BryanOlesky while this answers your exact question consider Preston Guillot's answer - it is very strange to accept `-5`, but reject `+5`.

Answer (score 3):

There is an overload of `Int32.TryParse` that accepts a `NumberStyles` value and an `IFormatProvider`. - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zf50za27(v=vs.110).aspx

The default used by `Int32.TryParse` is `NumberStyles.Integer`, which allows leading and trailing whitespace, and leading signs.

`int.TryParse("+5", NumberStyles.None, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out x)`, for example, returns false - however, it also returns false for -5, since the option to include a leading sign doesn't differentiate between a + and -. This is a hint that you probably shouldn't either, "+5" is every bit an integer as "5" and "-5".

Answer (score -1):

You can remove `+` from textBox at runtime or check + character as shown in below code

```
if (inputBox.Text.Contains("+"))
{
    // throw or show message
    return;
}
if (!int.TryParse(inputBox.Text, out input))
{
}
```

If you want to show popup while press, you can check above condition in textbox TextChangeEvent, 
Or use keypress event to restrict input.

Comment: That's good and all, but I want it to throw and error to the user.

Comment: @BryanOlesky you welcome, please mark it as solution

Comment: Sorry I'm making the answer above this the answer. It was more in-depth. Thank you anyways, I will be adding this to my mental library.

Comment: @BryanOlesky Where are you showing the message in accepted answer? because you mentioned above you want to show meesage